# How to define a function when proving two groups are not isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

So I am given two groups and I need to prove that they are not isomorphic. According to the definition of isomorphism,  the condition $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$ should be satisfied. Does it really matter how I define a function though?

For example, my function is $f(x) = x$ and my groups are $(\Bbb Q,+)$ and $(\Bbb Q_{>0}, \cdot)$. When I take arbitrary values from a group and substitute into $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$ I get a contradiction but I am unsure whether I've really proved that they are not isomorphic.

Comment: Yes, it does matter. Not every map between them will be an isomorphism. Indeed the map you describe is not even a proper map because $f(x)$ does not belong to $Q^+$ for $x<0$.

Comment: It is usually pretty trivial to define a function from one group to another that is not an isomorphism, but this doesn't prove some *other* function will not turn out to be an isomorphism.  So, yes, it does matter how you define the function (or prove non-existence in the alternative).

Comment: @almagest , not sure I understand what you mean. Could you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: I think you don't understand what the question is asking. You need to show that there does not exist an isomorphism between the two groups. The way to do that is to let $f$ be an arbitrary group homomorphism between the groups, and show that it cannot possibly be both injective and surjective.

Comment: @AlexG. , I am confused about defining a function in general (well at least I believe that's the reason...) Should I usually avoid it when proving/disproving isomorphism? I looked at your comment for the deleted answer. Did you try to prove there that addition of a number to itself is not always equal to a square root of some other number?

Comment: No, that's not what was going on. Just do the following: Suppose that $f: (\Bbb Q, +) \to (\Bbb Q_{> 0}, \cdot)$ is a group homomorphism. Let $a = f(1)$. Now see what you can figure out about the other values of $f$ based on this one value. For instance, you should be able to figure out what $f(2), f(3), f(4), \ldots$ are by using the definition of "group homomorphism". Next, you can figure out what $f(-1), f(-2), \ldots$ are. Next you can figure out what $f(1/2), f(1/3), \ldots$ are. Eventually, you'll determine what $f(m/n)$ is for any $m/n \in \Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Multik You say you took the function $f(x)=x$ for groups $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ and $\mathbb{Q}^+,\cdot)$. The snag about that function is that it is not defined for $x<0$ because $\mathbb{Q}^+$ does not contain any negative values. So it is not even a bijection, let alone an isomorphism. Given any two groups $G,G'$ it is easy to find functions $f:G\to G'$ which are *not* isomorphisms. But that tells you nothing about whether they are isomorphic. You must either produce an isomorphism or prove that one is impossible.

Comment: Note that this mess can often be avoided by finding some property that one group has, but the other does not (like the property of being Abelian, or the property of having elements of a certain order).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I don't feel really confident but I think I understood this particular example. Thank you.